# KeyEvent not printing the commands

Tags: java

I'm creating a game using eclipse, and I was testing my player move event, so when I press the arrow keys, it should print on the console the direction my player should move for, according to the key (for example, if I press arrow right key, it should print "right" on the console, so I know its working), but nothing happens when I press the keys

```
package me.gusta.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import me.gusta.entities.Entity;
import me.gusta.entities.Player;
import me.gusta.graphics.Spritesheet;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    
    
    public static JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private final int WIDTH = 240;
    private final int HEIGHT =160;
    private final int SCALE =3;

    private BufferedImage image;
    
    public List<Entity> entities;
    public Spritesheet spritesheet;
    
    private Player player;
    
    public Game() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        initFrame();
        //Starting objects
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        spritesheet = new Spritesheet("/spritesheet.png");
        player = new Player(0,0,16,16,spritesheet.getSprite(32, 0, 16, 16));
        entities.add(player);
    }

public void initFrame() {
    
    frame = new JFrame("Game01");
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
}

public synchronized void start() {
    
    thread = new Thread(this);
    isRunning = true;
    thread.start();
    
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    isRunning = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
    
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
    }
    
    public void tick() {
        for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
            Entity e = entities.get(i);
            e.tick();
        }
    }
    
    public void render() {
        
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            
            return;
        }
        
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255 ));
        g.fillRect(0    , 0, WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        /*Render*/
        //Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;
        for(int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++) {
            Entity e = entities.get(i);
            e.render(g);
        }
        /***/
        g.dispose();
        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE, null);
        bs.show();
        
    }

    public void run() {
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
            double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
            double delta = 0;
            int frames = 0;
            double timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while(isRunning) {
            
                    long now = System.nanoTime();
                        delta+= (now - lastTime) / ns;
                        lastTime = now;
                        if(delta>= 1) {
                            tick();
                            render();
                            frames++;
                            delta--;
                        }
                        
                        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000) {
                            
                            System.out.println(frames);
                            frames = 0;
                            timer += 1000;
                        }
                        
                    }
        stop();
    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            System.out.println("Right");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            System.out.println("Left");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("Up");
        } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            System.out.println("Down");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Please run your program under the debugger, set breakpoints, and see if you can figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would split up your class into a main class with the main method, a class that is responsible for the view (Canvas, Frame and that stuff) and a controller class that handles the user input. This way, your project would be more structured and easier to extend.
Nevertheless, your current code seems to be correct. I've tried it (without the Entity, Player and Spritesheet stuff) and it did work.

Make sure to click on your game to focus it. Otherwise, you won't receive any *KeyEvents*.
Another thing you could try, is to verify that the *keyPressed* method is called at all (print something outside the if statements or set a breakpoint and debug)

Comment: I tried to print something outside of the if statements, but apparently the keyPressed method isnt working, idk why

Comment: Does it print out the frames every second? Maybe your program is stuck somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I implemented requestFocus(); and it worked, idk why it wasnt working earlier, even if I clicked the window to focus it manually